# vagrant@localhost:~$ /usr/bin/mysqld_safe & not working

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I am a beginner to programming world: Been googling and trying many things for two days... but no solution.
Installed cptserver for LAMP, for virtual machine (Git, vagrant, puppet): https://github.com/pigeontech/cptserver

When I try to start Mysql, I get the following errors:

```
vagrant@localhost:~$ /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
```

> [1] 3404 vagrant@localhost:~$ 160311 01:02:50 mysqld_safe Can't log to
>   error log and syslog at the same time.
>
> Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take
>   effect.
>
> 160311 01:02:50 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
>
> touch: cannot touch ‘/var/log/mysql/error.log’: Permission denied
>
> chmod: cannot access ‘/var/log/mysql/error.log’: Permission denied
>
> cat: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid: Permission denied
>
> rm: cannot remove ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid’: Permission denied
>
> 160311 01:02:50 mysqld_safe Fatal error: Can't remove the pid file:
>   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
>
> Please remove it manually and start /usr/bin/mysqld_safe again; mysqld
>   daemon not started
>
> /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: 126: /usr/bin/mysqld_safe: cannot create
>   /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied
>
> vagrant@localhost:~$ [1]+  Exit 1
>   /usr/bin/mysqld_safe

Can some one show me a solution in simple way?

Answer (score 0):

At last, I could resolve it by the following steps:

```
$ sudo mysql_install_db

/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

$ sudo /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &
```

Opened a new window (Alt + F2) and brought the cursor to vagrant@localhost:~$

Then, opened MySQL by:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p mysql
```